# LibGDX loading scene2D widgets very slow for first time, need suggestions

Tags: java, android, menu, libgdx, scene2d

I started using scene2D in my LibGDX game to make a more professional looking login/register menu. The only problem is that switching to those menus is very long for menu navigation (3-5 sec).

I want to know if there is a better way to load them before hand, like during the game's initial loading screen. The thing is that once one of the menus is loaded, it loads very quick the second time.

I know for sure that its the `create` method of my screens that takes this long. Here is all that it is loading:

```
public void create(){
    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(1920, 1080));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    loginBox = new Image(Textures.Gui.BOX);
    loginBox.setSize(650, 1000);
    loginBox.setPosition(635, 40);
    stage.addActor(loginBox);
    loginLBL = new Label("Login", Archipelo.SKIN, "basic-large-font", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    loginLBL.setPosition(880, 955); 
    stage.addActor(loginLBL);
    selectionHighlight = new Image(Textures.Gui.SELECTION_HIGHLIGHT);
    selectionHighlight.setSize(540, 140);
    stage.addActor(selectionHighlight);
    usernameTF = new TextField("", Archipelo.SKIN);
    usernameTF.setMaxLength(24);
    usernameTF.setPosition(usernameTFx, usernameTFy);
    usernameTF.setSize(400, 60);
    stage.addActor(usernameTF);
    passwordTF = new TextField("", Archipelo.SKIN);
    passwordTF.setPasswordMode(true);
    passwordTF.setPasswordCharacter('•');
    passwordTF.setPosition(passwordTFx, passwordTFy);
    passwordTF.setSize(400, 60);
    stage.addActor(passwordTF);
    usernameLBL = new Label("Username", Archipelo.SKIN, "basic-medium-font", new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.5f));
    usernameLBL.setPosition(usernameTFx + 10, usernameTFy + 5);
    stage.addActor(usernameLBL);
    passwordLBL = new Label("Password", Archipelo.SKIN, "basic-medium-font", new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.5f));
    passwordLBL.setPosition(passwordTFx + 10, passwordTFy + 5);
    stage.addActor(passwordLBL);
    remember = new CheckBox(" Remember Login?", Archipelo.SKIN);
    remember.setPosition(rememberX, rememberY);
    remember.getCells().get(0).size(30, 30);
    stage.addActor(remember);
    errorLBL = new Label("", Archipelo.SKIN, "basic-small-font", Color.RED);
    errorLBL.setPosition(750, 650);
    errorLBL.setWrap(true);
    errorLBL.setBounds(750, 500, 400, 250);
    stage.addActor(errorLBL);
    continueLBL = new Label("Continue", Archipelo.SKIN, "basic-big-font", Color.WHITE);
    continueLBL.setPosition(875, 100);
    stage.addActor(continueLBL);
}
```

Also, I load the uiskin files before in the game's initial loading screen. `Archipelo.SKIN` is a static variable that refers to that uiskin. I also wanted to mention that my screen class is custom made and that whenever `create()` is called it is because a new screen instance is being created.

The thing that I don't get is why it takes so long to create the screen the first time and then every other time, it still goes through the same process except its much faster. Is there a way to make it faster the first time?

Thanks in advance. If you need more info by all means ask.

Comment: What does the line that defines `Textures.Gui.BOX` look like? Maybe you are unintentionally doing some kind of lazy loading of Textures. Make sure your textures are loaded ahead of time while the user is on some loading screen.

Comment: It's a 650x1000 pixel texture. I tried pin pointing what widget was taking so long to load and I couldn't. Sometimes it would be a textbox and other times it was and image or even a label. it was pretty random

Comment: Still not clear to me. Do you define it as `public static Texture BOX;` and load it with a method, or do you define it as  `public static Texture BOX = new Texture("texturefile.png");` or something else?

Comment: I have a class called `Textures`. In there I have sub-classes, the one that the Box texture is in is the `Gui` sub-class (Just a way to organize myself). All the textures there are `public static final`

Comment: Since you are using `final`, does that mean you are loading them in the declaration, like this: `public static Texture BOX = new Texture("texturefile.png");`? That would explain your problem. All the static final members of your Gui class will get loaded only the first time any one of the members is accessed (which triggers loading of the Gui class). So the first time you access anything in Gui, it will suddenly have to initialize all the static members, so if you are one-lining them like this, the app will pause to load all those textures declared in Gui.

Comment: If you want control over when the Textures are loaded, you can't use the `final` keyword, and you need to use a method to instantiate them. I don't recommend storing Textures in a static variable anyway, because it is a very easy way to create memory leaks. The way I handle it is with my own Assets class that has its own instance of AssetManager to handle all the loading and unloading of Textures. Assets could be a singleton to avoid passing its reference around, but you'd need to be very careful about when to unload stuff. I just go ahead and pass the reference around.

Comment: Thanks! I will make a loading menu or something. Iwas always under the impression that final variables loaded as soon as the program starts. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I used to think that true, but if you think about it, that would force any app using a library project to waste a bunch of time and memory loading every static member from every class it's not using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments...

The OP had a convenience class for texture references, that listed the textures like this:

```
public class Gui {

    public static final Texture BOX = new Texture("box.png");
    public static final Texture SELECTION_HIGHLIGHT= new Texture("selectionHighlight.png");
    //...

}
```

Since they are declared `static`, they are members of the class, not an instance of a class. Static members of a class are all initialized at once, but only the first time the class or an instance of the class is accessed. This setup results in all the Gui textures getting loaded all at once at some inopportune, unplanned time.

The Texture's constructor `Texture(String filename)` causes a texture to be loaded from a file, which is time-consuming, so the loading of the Gui class takes a few seconds.

The solution is to not instantiate member texture variables in their declaration. Instantiate them within some method so you can decide exactly when they should be loaded.